# Github: reset to previous commit

Tags: git, github

Small team. A colleague pushed to `origin:master` by mistake. He has reset his local repo but cannot `push -f` to Github because repo is **protected**.

I have `fetch`ed the repo but not merged his errant commit into my local `master`...yet.

How can I, assuming I can `push -f` to origin, reset `origin` on Github so that it reflects the state it was in before his mistake?

```
$ git push origin 2860a4c:master
To github.com:example/myproj.git
 ! [rejected]        2860a4c -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:example/myproj.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Do I really need to integrate the bad commit (with `git pull`) before I can then, I assume, `reset hard 2860a4c` and then `push -f origin`?

I just don't want to make things worse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: I know there are a lot (too many?) of posts here about reverting git commits. However, I haven't found one that clearly explains how to remove (reset) last commit on Github.  I suppose I could `revert` the commit, but I'm trying to find a way to just undo that last Github commit, without blowing up local repos, if possible.

Comment: Without `-f` you can not do it. You need to revert that commit using `git revert` but that will be the part of your history

Comment: Do you have permission to do `-f`

Comment: "Assume I have permission to `push -f`" so yes, i have permission (or can grant it for the time being).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Below are the steps you may do, assuming **you have permission for `git push -f`**.

On your machine, do:

```
# Step 1: Take the changes from remote
git pull

# Step 2: Note the commit to which you want for restoring your repo to 
# using `git log`. Say the commit id is "x". 
git log

# Step 3: Do hard reset for that commit. 
#         ** NOTE ** All the changes after the commit "x" will be removed
git reset --hard x    # where x is the commit id

# Step 4: Push to remote
git push -f
```

Then on collegue's machine, do `step 1` to `step 3` and then do `git pull` to merge the remote changes

---

In case **you do NOT have permission for `git push -f`**, do:

```
git pull

git revert <commit id>   # may get it via "git log"

git push
```

With `git revert`, changes from the reverted commit will be removed, but this commit will remain in the commit history.

Answer (score 2):

If you can `push -f`, than do it. If the state you want is one commit before the top, you can run

```
git pull
git reset --hard @~1
git push -f
```

Be sure everyone else in the team is in sync, so they don't lose any work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pull bad commit, therefore `git reset` is not needed neither.
If I understood the question correctly `git push --force` should be sufficient. It will bring remote's state to yours.

In case you've already pulled bad commit, use `git reset --hard` + `git push --force` as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37145089/1663197.

Comment: >How can I, assuming I can push -f to origin